# composer-rest-server doesnt connect (failed to obtain cds for digitalproperty-network)

Tags: hyperledger-composer

Installed playground with the steps from:
[Using playground locally](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/installing/using-playground-locally.html)

Trying for 2 days now to get the composer-rest-server starting.

Steps done:

- Changed all the ca/peer/orderer urls from "localhost" to their specific docker IPs in the ~/.composer-connection-profiles/hlfv1/connection.json, otherwise i just get a connection timeout when starting the composer-rest-server
- Deployed the "digitalproperty-network" with composer
- Got myself a new identity via composer and the secret

Now when i run:

```
> composer-rest-server -p hlfv1 -n digitalproperty-network -i baderth -s omgDBCimVAbB -N always
```

Im just getting:

> Discovering types from business network definition ...
>
> Error: failed to obtain cds for digitalproperty-network - transaction
>   not found digitalproperty-network/mychannel
>       at /usr/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/fabric-client/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:434:17 code: 2, metadata: Metadata { _internal_repr: {} } }

Same error also shown in the latest file in the /logs directory.

I have no clue what "transaction not found digitalproperty-network/mychannel" means and what i should provide the rest server with if not the digitalproperty-network, which i deployed.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the install instructions for setting up a Development Environment, and then the Developer Guide:

- https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/installing/development-tools.html
- https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/developer-guide.html

Comment: managed to start the rest-server, seems some has to deploy it from the commandline instead of composer-web. netstat shows its listening on *:3000, but it isnt serving anything. browser times out, even a simple telnet to port 3000 isnt working. also disabled ipv6 entirely with no luck.

Comment: Can you describe the exact steps you took to start the rest server and any output please.

Comment: Debian8. followed your first link. Docker: 17.03, compose: 1.13, node: 6.11

Comment: Had to alter the connection.json to docker images IPs instead of localhost, otherwise got a connection timeout to the ca, although all ports are mapped. (strange, maybe here is the "error").
This is what I ended up with: https://pastebin.com/p0wynucx
compose deploy and ping are working.
Now starting rest-server, no error no nothing:
https://pastebin.com/UY4N348K

Netstat output: https://pastebin.com/hwZJiT5B